# Type cast char array[16] to int 128 bits

Tags: c++, c

I have two 16bytes char array:

```
char word[WORD_LENGTH] = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6','7','8','9','0','1','2','3','4','5','\0'};
char word2[WORD_LENGTH] = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6','7','8','9','0','1','2','3','4','5','\0'};
```

I'm looking for a way to compare two char arrays faster than compare character by character would be. From my knowledge, I think that I can convert char array into 128 int using type casting; like this

```
__int128 value = (__int128) word;
__int128 value2 = (__int128) word2;
```

But these doesn't work, because value and value2 contains the address of word and word2.

How I convert char array into __int128?

Comment: use pointer or union, but still you'll have endianity problem

Comment: C or C++? You know they are different languages, right?

Comment: but it doesn't matter the order of bits, I only want to check if this words are the same.

Comment: have you tried `memcmp`?

Comment: @SHR I think type cast is more faster than memcmp because is directly.

Comment: On what cpu is this thing gonna run and what compiler is gonna be used?

Comment: @RCalaf i'm not sure. `memcmp` is optimize in most of the compilers since it one of the most usable codes.

Comment: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770 and I'm using gcc version 4.7.2 and icc version 15.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE: You're asking about two languages, and don't indicate which you're actually using. I'll try to answer for both, but my knowledge of C is some years out of date, so I might get some details wrong there.

There are several options; you'll have to measure them to determine which is fastest in your environment.

A good implementation of `std::equal` (in C++) or `memcmp` (in C) might be optimised for small arrays of known size. That might be good enough.

The only well-defined way to reinterpret the bytes as another type is to copy them:

```
__int128 value;
copy(begin(word), end(word), reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value));  // C++
memcpy((char*)(&value), word, WORD_SIZE)                        // C
```

The compiler might or might not optimise this to load words rather than bytes.

If all else fails, you can resort to formally undefined behaviour:

```
__int128 value = *reinterpret_cast<__int128*>(word); // *(__int128*)word in C
```

On some platforms, this might fail if the arrays aren't suitably aligned, or for other reasons.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use memcmp.

Are you sure that the compiler you are using is gonna then compare the int128 in some special part of the cpu where 128integers can be compared togheter?
Because if it splits in 32 bit pars it will be useless.

```
int memcmp(word, word2, 16)
```

If you are looking for the extreme performance case, you have to compare the ASM derived from different implementation of this logic

Consider also that 128bit math is in the domain of mmx or sse or avx. As far as a i know, those are meant to be used on multiple set of data togheter, i don't think that using them for a single compare is usefull in terms of speed gain.

if it would be usefull in term of performance i bet that gcc, icc and other c compiler would do this 128bit, 256bit comparing as an internal optimization of memcmp more than leaving the idea to the user.

Comment: memcmp is implemented in assember in the most of the compilers.

Comment: Of course, that is why i proposed it. int128 are those common?

Comment: Not very much common yet, maybe when 128 bit OS will become common.

Comment: The memcmp function is slower than sse+type casting, because sse use 128 bits registers. However, sse + type casting only runs when array are aligned.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
__int128 value = *(__int128 *)word;
```

Comment: This is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @AntonSavin: True, but this could be helpful is speed is more important than portability (after checking how your compiler handles this, of course).

Comment: It's likely already outside of the standard by using __int128 so yes, you have to be careful of course, but it might be a good solution on a given compiler. (With suitable care and knowledge about what you are doing)

Comment: Casting an array of byte (indirectly, through a pointer cast) to an `__int128` is undefined behaviour indeed. But ISTM that is what the question wants.

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard comparison function `memcmp`, and let the compiler worry about optimising your code:

```
memcmp(word, word2, WORD_LENGTH)
```

If after profiling you find that this is not fast enough for you, you can worry about improving that (e.g. by using a union, or by using SSE2 intrinsics) — but you will most likely find it difficult to beat a good implementation of memcmp.